# infinite scroll loading in new page

Tags: jquery

I am using the same infinite scroll scripts that I have used before but for some reason the results just post into a new window.

Here is the template that calls the snippet that has the infinite scroll:

```
 <div id="mainContent">

<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="blog-posts">
      <h1>News Blog</h1>
        {snip_ajax_scroll}
    </div>
    <script src="{site_url}assets/javascripts/jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>
    <script src="{site_url}assets/javascripts/manual-trigger.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#blog-posts').infinitescroll({
                behavior     : 'twitter',
                navSelector : ".blog-more-entries",
                nextSelector : "a.more",
                itemSelector : ".article",
                contentSelector: "#blog-posts",
                extractLink: true, // This is crucial if you want it work properly. Setting this to false or excluding it will not allow the script to work with EE
            })
        });
        // Unbind normal behavior
        $(window).unbind('.infscr');

        // Bind normal behavior to the click function and prevent the browser from redirecting to the URL.
        $('a.more').click(function(){
            $(document).trigger('retrieve.infscr');
            return false;
         });
    </script> 

    <div id="blog-sidebar">
      <h4>Categories List</h4>
      <ul>
        {exp:channel:categories}
            <li><a href="{path='news/article'}">{category_name}</a></li>
        {/exp:channel:categories}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- /.wrapper -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
</div> <!-- /#mainContent -->
```

And this is the snippet:

```
            {exp:channel:entries
            channel="news"
            dynamic="yes"
            order_by="date"
            limit="4"
            status="open" 
            paginate_base="_embeds/ajax_scroll"       
        }
        <div class="article">
            <div class="header">
              <h2><a href="{path='news/article'}">{title}</a></h2>
              <span class="postdate">{entry_date format="%D, %F %d, %Y"}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-preview">
                {if news_image}
                    <p><img src="{news_image}" alt="{title}" title="{title}"></p>
                {/if}

                {exp:word_limit total="25"}{exp:remove_html}{news_article}{/exp:remove_html}{/exp:word_limit}
                <a href="{path='news/article'}" class="blog-read-more">Read More &rarr;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>     

        {paginate}
        <p class="blog-more-entries">
            {if next_page}<a href="{auto_path}" class="more"><img src="{site_url}assets/images/btn-see-more-entries.png" alt="See More Entries"></a>{/if}
        </p>
        {/paginate}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

I also have an embed that is called by the snippet that just includes it again to populate the next set of entries.

Jquery is loading above the scripts and it is working on a different site, but just not this one.  I am using EE 2.7.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this one? What do you mean by "the results just post into a new window."?

Comment: When I click "show more posts" it shows the next set of results in a new browser window without any styling. the url has the pagination address in it, so it ends up being "www.myurl.com/_embeds/ajax_scroll".

Comment: Ok, that is more of a general javascript question that an ExpressionEngine one .. you might have more luck trying the main stackexchange site.